# Azure VMSS without a public ip

Tags: azure, azure-vm-scale-set

I am trying to create a azure virtual machine scale set (VMSS) without a public ip for rolling upgrade policy (zero downtime). All the examples I find requires a configuration with a public IP. Even the wizard on azure forces to create a public ip. Can a VMSS with rolling upgrade be created without a public ip?

I can create a manual upgrade_policy VMSS without a loadbalancer or healthprobe without public ips. But I am unable to create a 'Rolling' upgrade_policy vmss without public ip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Q: Can a VMSS be created without a public ip? if so how?**

Why not? When you create the VMSS in the Azure portal like the screenshot below, you do not need to select to use a load balancer, then it will create a VMSS without any public IP.

[image]

**Update:**

Take a look at the screenshot below:

**Rolling upgrade policy**

[image]

VMSS configuration

[image]

As you see, the VMSS still does not have the public IP, but the rolling upgrade policy is set as you want. You just need to set the monitor application health extension:

[image]

Comment: The rolling upgrade policy requires a healthprobe and it ends up creating a public ip at the end if you checked. I already mentioned that with manual upgrade_policy i can create a vmss without public ips. I am trying to create a rolling upgrade policy VMSS.

Comment: @SivaVg What about the update? Does it solve your problem? If it works for you please accept it.